# Xcode project does not appear on the Apple Developer website

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on a project in Xcode, The developer team doesn't appear on the Apple Developer website, only these options.

I really need the rest of the options 
I want to do a notification on my app for a school project. I really need the rest of the options.
Thank you all.

[image]

Comment: are you sure you paid for an apple developer account, it strikes me as you're trying to login to developer account using a normal iTunes account which is actually free. You need to pay $99 / year to get a developer account to be able to develop iOS apps.

Comment: Are you sure that you are added as a developer in your team? please check.

Comment: If you won't register as paid developer, those options won't come

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot and the minimum information it provides, I assume you're not logged in using an apple developer account.

There are two ways you can get an apple developer access,

1) You can pay $99 / Year to get a developer account for yourself, I am not entirely sure how this works for educational purposes, You can mail the apple support for any discount.

2) Anyone who has an enterprise apple developer account can add you as a developer under their account.

Without these two ways, you can't explore the apple developer options.